# Regarding a proof of Tarski-Knaster's fixed point theorem

Tags: proof-verification, order-theory, fixed-point-theorems, lattice-orders

I'm trying to prove the following theorem,

> Let $(X, \leq)$ be a complete lattice. If $\phi:X \to X$ is order preserving, it has a fixed point.

So far, I've done the following:

I've defined the set $A := \{a \in X : a \leq \phi(a)\} $. Since $\inf{X} \in A$, $A$ is non empty and therefore we can consider $x_0 := \sup{A}$. Now, since $\phi$ is order preserving,

$$
a \leq \phi(a) \leq \phi(x_0) \ \ \ (\forall a \in A)
$$

This shows that $\phi(x_0)$ is an upper bound of $A$, and therefore $x_0 \leq \phi(x_0)$. Again, because $\phi$ is order preserving, this implies $\phi(x_0) \leq \phi(\phi(x_0))$ which means that $\phi(x_0) \in A$, so $\phi(x_0) \leq x_0$, (supposedly) completing the proof.

Is this correct?

Comment: Also known as the Tarski--Knaster Theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is quite correct. Why do you doubt this? All steps have been justified, IMHO. The last step is just $\phi(x_0) \le x_0$ and $x_0 \le \phi(x_0)$ implies $\phi(x_0) = x_0$ by the axioms for partial orders, so $x_0$ is a fixpoint for $\phi$. (Why the supposedly?)

Comment: To be honest, I've seen this in a class about cardinality, as an auxiliary result to prove the Cantor - Schröder - Bernstein theorem. My professor left this result as an exercise and this is the first time I've worked with lattices, so I wasn't sure every step was well justified.  Thanks!

Comment: @GuidoA. yes, this proof can be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TarskisFixedPointTheorem.html) as well (not too nice mark-up though).